# Firebase Analytics не работает

Tags: android, firebase

Пытался настроить Firebase Analytics и Crashlytics, но не получилось. В дашборде аналитики нету активности, хотя приложение запускалось. Также, в дашборде crashlytics отсутствует информация о критических ошибках, хотя они были.

Я поместил `google-services.json` в `/project/app-module/`

Мой `/project/build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}
```

Мой `/project/app-module/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.yh.devicehelper'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yh.devicehelper"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}
```

Comment: какие именно ошибки были? насколько я знаю по мануалу Firebase желательно непосредственно после подключения проекта к дашборду сгенерировать мануально ошибку, то есть вызвать Exception к примеру

Comment: @Andrew так и сделал, специально вызывал exception, но в дашборде пусто

Comment: тогда я бы предложил удалить и добавить заново проект в дашборд, добавить зависимости и пересобрать Firebase в AS, такое случается что с первого раза не долетают краши

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо за помощь! Проблема заключается в том, что ни эмулятор, ни физическое устройство не могут подключится к серверам firebase с российского ip. Но если включить vpn, то все заработает